# Spinner text doesn't fit to its parent

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm using `Spinner` which is multiline and I'm experiencing problem with its parent border.

I expect behavior similar to `TextView` or any other `View`. If its `wrap_content` (height), it should change its height if multiline option is selected from dropdown. But it doesn't work and portion of the text is cut in a half and hidden behind parent.

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="50dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_background_ok"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        app:errorEnabled="true"
                        android:overlapAnchor="false"
                        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                        android:singleLine="false"/>

                </LinearLayout>
```

Picture example:

[image]

Adapter:

```
class SpinnerAdapter(private val a: Activity, resource: Int, private val optionList: MutableList<Item>) :
    ArrayAdapter<Item>(a, resource, optionList) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        return customView(position, parent)
    }

    override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        return customView(position, parent)
    }

    private fun customView(position: Int, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val customItemView = a.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false)
        val currentlyPicked = optionList[position]
        val optionString = customItemView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.option)
        optionString?.isSingleLine = false
        optionString?.text = currentlyPicked.getName()
        if (position == count) optionString?.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(a, R.color.Grey))
        else name?.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(a, R.color.Black))

        return customItemView
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        val count = super.getCount()
        return if (count > 0) count - 1 else count
    }
}
```

Item View:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/option"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/normal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Option"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you share your code for spinner too ?

Comment: how do you populate your spinner ? with an adapter ? can you post if it's the case tha code for this adapter ?

Comment: Remove `android:minHeight="50dp"` from your `LinearLayout`

Comment: If I remove it, parent height would be random each time. I need minimum height to fit design of other views.

Comment: @martin1337 can you post this layout too ? "spinner_item"

Comment: can you post xml from spinner_item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change your `spinner_item` like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  // do not fix the height of this layout.
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/option"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/normal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Option"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:minHeight="50dp"` and set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in **`Spinner`**.